# Filter dataframe by finding keyword inside a chunk of text

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with Twitter data in a dataframe. I want to filter the column that holds the text of each tweet according to a certain keyword found within the text.

I've tried str.contains but that doesn't work, as the column is a Series. I want to filter the "text" column for all the tweets containing the keyword 'remoaners'.

```
remoaners_only = time_plus_text[time_plus_text["text"].str.contains("remoaners", case=False, na=False)]
```

This produces either an empty dataframe or a lot of NaNs.

pandas version is 0.24.1.

Here's the input data: time_plus_text["text"].head(10)

```
0    [ #bbcqt Remoaners on about post Brexit racial...
1    [@sarahwollaston Shut up, you like all remoane...
2    [ what have the Brextremists ever done for us ...
3                     [ Remoaner in bizarre outburst ]
4    [ Anyone who disagrees with brexit is called n...
5    [ @SkyNewsBreak They forecasted if the vote wa...
6    [ but we ARE LEAVING THE #EU, even the #TORIES...
7    [ Can unelected Remoaner peers not see how abs...
8    [@sizjam68 @LeaveEUOfficial @johnredwood It wo...
9    [ Hey @BBC have you explained why when award w...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, it would be easier for people to help you if you share some input data to be able to reproduce your problem. Here it would be the first few lines of your column `time_plus_text["text"]`. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details

Comment: Could you add sample data? This should work I think. Which pandas are you using?

Comment: updated, thanks for tips, hope its clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the string you want to find the substring `remoaners` in is contained in a `list` in each cell. You need to access this string by doing `str[0]` before doing `str.contains` such as:

```
# input
time_plus_text = pd.DataFrame({'text':[['#bbcqt Remoaners on about post Brexit racial...'], 
                                       ['@sarahwollaston Shut up, you like all remoaners...'],
                                       ['what have the Brextremists ever done for us ...']]})
print (time_plus_text["text"].str[0].str.contains("remoaners", case=False, na=False))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

so you should do:

```
remoaners_only = time_plus_text[time_plus_text["text"].str[0]\
                                             .str.contains("remoaners", case=False, na=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.  So you are left to check your input data or the pandas bug fix version, 0.24.1 vs 0.24.2.

```
0.24.2
   index                                               text
0      0     [ #bbcqt Remoaners on about post Brexit rac...
```

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""0,   [ #bbcqt Remoaners on about post Brexit racial...
1,   [@sarahwollaston Shut up, you like all remoane...
2,   [ what have the Brextremists ever done for us ...
3,                    [ Remoaner in bizarre outburst ]
4,   [ Anyone who disagrees with brexit is called n...
5,   [ @SkyNewsBreak They forecasted if the vote wa...
6,   [ but we ARE LEAVING THE #EU, even the #TORIES...
7,   [ Can unelected Remoaner peers not see how abs...
8,   [@sizjam68 @LeaveEUOfficial @johnredwood It wo...
9,   [ Hey @BBC have you explained why when award w...""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, names=["index", "text"], sep=",")

result = df[df["text"].str.contains("remoaners", case=False, na=False)]

# results
print(result)
```